# Tensorflow: Different results upon restoring session

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Within one tab I run and save a model, then within another I load the session that was saved immediately before. 
I then use the loaded session to predict values on a data set. The weights of the model can be seen to be the same when printed to the terminal. Strangely though, the predictions on the loaded session are wildly inaccurate and completely different from those of the trained session. 
This is a recurrent network. Any ideas what's going wrong?

```html
def dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1,n_input])
    #x  = tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden'])+ biases['hidden']
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output, providing 'sequence_length' will perform dynamic
    # calculation.
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seqlen)

    # When performing dynamic calculation, we must retrieve the last
    # dynamically computed output, i.e, if a sequence length is 10, we need
    # to retrieve the 10th output.
    # However TensorFlow doesn't support advanced indexing yet, so we build
    # a custom op that for each sample in batch size, get its length and
    # get the corresponding relevant output.

    # 'outputs' is a list of output at every timestep, we pack them in a Tensor
    # and change back dimension to [batch_size, n_step, n_input]
    outputs = tf.pack(outputs)
    outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])

    # Hack to build the indexing and retrieve the right output.
    batch_size = tf.shape(outputs)[0]
    # Start indices for each sample
    index = tf.range(0, batch_size) * n_steps + (seqlen - 1)
    # Indexing
    outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden]), index)

    # Linear activation, using outputs computed above
    return tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']

def RNNpred(test_x, test_seqlen):
    saver.restore(sess,'./variables/dynamicRNNreturnReason.ckpt')
    y_prob, y_pred= sess.run([pred, y_p], feed_dict={x: test_x, seqlen: test_seqlen})
    return y_prob, y_pred

n_steps = 10
n_input = 14
n_classes = 6
n_hidden = 100
weights = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]), name='W')}
biases = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name='b')}
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
pred = dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases)
y_p =tf.argmax(pred,1)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: What does your code for restoring the model look like? (i.e. Where do you call `RNNpred()`?)

Comment: It is a few lines in a separate file while manages predictions across different models:
def getRNNpred(test_x, test_seq):
    from file import RNNpred
    return RNNpred(test_x, test_seq)

Comment: So the error is most likely in how the code in the question interacts with this snippet of code. To figure out the cause, we'll need an end to end example that shows how the calls to `tf.Session()`, `dynamicRNN()`, `sess.run()`, and `RNNpred()` are ordered.

Comment: By placing print statements after each of the events. By running getRNNPred I found them to be ordered:
getRNNPred called, session called, session init called, session restored (within RNNpred)